# How to set the limit of number of bounding boxes over the image with SelectAreas.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bounding-box

I have been developing a code to tag images using the reference from this project.

https://rawgit.com/360Learning/jquery-select-areas/master/example/example.html

From the reference page you can , the user can draw many bounding boxes over the image. But what i would like to do is to restrict the bounding box to just one. i.e., the user can draw only one bounding box over the image , when he draws the next one, the previous one should disappear.

Html:

```
 <div class="image-decorator">
            <img alt="Image principale" id="example" src="example.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="actions">
                    <input type="button" id="btnView" value="Display areas" class="actionOn" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnViewRel" value="Display relative" class="actionOn" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnNew" value="Add New" class="actionOn" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnNews" value="Add 2 New" class="actionOn" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" class="actionOn" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnDestroy" value="Destroy" class="actionOn" />
                    <input type="button" id="btnCreate" value="Create" class="actionOff" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="output" class='output'> </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('img#example').selectAreas({
                minSize: [10, 10],
                onChanged: debugQtyAreas,
                width: 500,
                areas: [
                    {
                        x: 10,
                        y: 20,
                        width: 60,
                        height: 100,
                    }
                ]
            });

  $('#btnNew').click(function () {
                var areaOptions = {
                    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 200)),
                    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 200)),
                    width: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 50,
                    height: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 20,
                };
                output("Add a new area: " + areaToString(areaOptions))
                $('img#example').selectAreas('add', areaOptions);
            });
            $('#btnNews').click(function () {
                var areaOption1 = {
                    x: Math.floor((Math.random() * 200)),
                    y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 200)),
                    width: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 50,
                    height: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100)) + 20,
                }, areaOption2 = {
                    x: areaOption1.x + areaOption1.width + 10,
                    y: areaOption1.y + areaOption1.height - 20,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 20,
                };
                output("Add a new area: " + areaToString(areaOption1) + " and " + areaToString(areaOption2))
                $('img#example').selectAreas('add', [areaOption1, areaOption2]);
            });
        });

        var selectionExists;

        function areaToString (area) {
            return (typeof area.id === "undefined" ? "" : (area.id + ": ")) + area.x + ':' + area.y  + ' ' + area.width + 'x' + area.height + '<br />'
        }

        function output (text) {
            $('#output').html(text);
        }

        // Log the quantity of selections
        function debugQtyAreas (event, id, areas) {
            console.log(areas.length + " areas", arguments);
        };

        // Display areas coordinates in a div
        function displayAreas (areas) {
            var text = "";
            $.each(areas, function (id, area) {
                text += areaToString(area);
            });
            output(text);
        };
```

the above code is used from the create several bounding boxes on the image. But i would like to create only one bounding box over the image and it disappears if I create a new one .
Can someone help me with this problem.